# Xcode 7 & El Capitan build fails

Tags: xcode, build, xcode7, osx-elcapitan

After El Capitan upgrade both Xcode 7.01 and Xcode 7.1.0-Beta now fail to Build or Clean or even preform syntax highlighting. I have rebooted and deleted Xcode(s) and reinstalled Xcode without luck.

I dropped back to Xcode 7.0 in desperation also without luck.

Comment: can you explain better your problem? Is too generic

Comment: Yes it is generic old boy

Comment: Chiming in to 2nd this issue. I'm getting a message "The operation couldn’t be completed. (FBSOpenApplicationErrorDomain error 1.)"

Comment: Apple said to remove ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData directory.

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be an Apple problem.

I had this problem with El Capitan production release and Xcode Version 7.1 beta (7B75). In my case Xcode would not Build or Clean and the Simulators failed to install.

So I ran xcode per the command below in a terminal:
sudo /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode

This corrected both the simulators issue and my build and clean failures. Unfortunately if I return to my usual spot-light xcode start the Build Clean failures resume. So I am back using the sudo start until Apple fixes this.

Comment: Apple got back, remove ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData directory and things work again.